# centos vsftp virtual users gui manager

Tags: centos, ftp

I tried to setup virtual users of VSFTP using the plain text (ssh) tutorials but unable to do so.
Is there any GUI based application to manage these virtual users? I am sure there must be some package?

Comment: Forgive the assumption, but you sound new to Unix-like systems. Some advice: don't be so sure about the existence of a GUI. You're overestimating the difficulty of editing config files. What's the *specific* issue you had with editing the config files? I guarantee if you post that you'll get quick answers. Were you unable to SSH into your machine? Were you unable to edit the conf file (probably /etc/vsftpd.conf)? Or did the changes you made to the conf file not have the effect you expected?

Comment: Oh yeah, and which tutorial are you using (link)?

Comment: hi,
this is what I used. http://linuxforfun.net/2008/04/05/vsftpd-virtual-users/
I successfully created the virtual users file but when I restarted the FTP service then both sets of users stopped working. Now, I think that there is no such GUI and I will have to do this the text way. I will keep you posted. Let me try this Again.

Comment: used this one actually. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/centos-redhat-vsftpd-ftp-with-virtual-users.html

Comment: The error it is giving me is: 500 - Oops - Missing value in config file - on a template.
note: this error on the restart step.

Comment: Then check your config file carefully to check you didn't make any small mistake.

Comment: yep, intend to. Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html).
There are [several](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=vsftp) plugins for doing vsftp maintenance.

Comment: Yes, this seems likea good thing to start from. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, installed webmin but I cannot access it through http://ipaddress:20000
I changed the port to 20000 as it was saying of 10000 already being used. Even still, I cannot access webmin. The service is running but nothing displays. I can tell that we are running a vhost ready apache and all port 80 traffic is sent to the folders but we never handled port 20000. Can we put webmin to a subdomain and send traffic through apache maybe?

Comment: webmin does not use apache, it uses an internal http server. Are you sure the service is started and there is no firewall blocking port 20000 ? Make sure you use https://ipaddress:port

Comment: ok I added port 20000 to the iptables and restarted the service. Accessing the webmin through our external service but firefox times out.

Comment: got it to install. needed to add accept 20000 port to iptables but before any reject lines. now working. thanks

Comment: hi @dercelus, I am using webmin but all users that I create are without permission to change the chmod of any directories? Any help?